# Sending email by using java applications

Tags: java, email, activation

I added mail.jar and activation.jar to my class path but i dont know how use them.
I just want to send a mail with this application.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Comment: Please show some effort before asking your question here. There are plenty of tutorials covering this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following library: https://github.com/CloudRail/cloudrail-si-java-sdk

You can send email choosing between SendGrid and Mailjet.
For example:

`Email mailjet = new Mailjet(null, "clientId", "clientSecret");
 mailjet.sendEmail("fromEmail", "fromName", toAddresses, "subject", "textBody", "htmlBody", ccAddresses, bccAddresses);`